# How to get to notifications in settings?

Tags: notifications, settings

The title sounds misleading... There exists a shortcut under the settings shortcut widget that points to notifications. In this I can see all the notifications that my phone had (even after clearing it in the pulldown notification tray).

I have 2 questions: a) where is it actually located in the settings (I have been looking for it for a while) b) how do I clear this...there seems to be no option (do I reboot?)

Here are the screenshots that may help clarify:

[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]
[image: Screenshot] [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you be more precise in what your asking? What is the end goal you are looking to achieve?

Comment: @John under android jb, there is a widget called "settings shortcut" which allows you to pick a shortcut to any setting. One of these shortcuts is to something called "Notifications". This window is shown in the last picure. It contains notifications (including ones i cleared from the dropdown bar). I like this feature and was wondering how to get to it aside from using the widget as i do not want to clutter my homescreen. I would assume it lives under settings because i found it under the "settings shortcut' widget, but i cant seem to find it anywher.

Comment: So you want to know how to get to that screen without using the widget if I am not mistaken? Also which version of Android are you running? Are you running a custom ROM?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I am running stock jb 4.3 build jwr66v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get at this activity other than through a settings shortcut. The code for it can be found [here on Github](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/NotificationStation.java), and if you search the repository for the `NotificationStation` class you'll find all the entry points for it: in this case, only the shortcut intent filter in the manifest. If you examine the code you'll also see there's no way to remove old notifications from the list: as you can see in the screenshot, the greyed-out notifications are those you've dismissed from the 'normal' notification tray.

However, this class is mainly intended as a demo. Android 4.3 adds support for any application (with the appropriate permission) to access and display the list of notifications. For example, a third-party launcher might want to show them, an app might want to show all notifications in a pop-up window iOS-style, a live wallpaper or daydream could respond to them graphically, or a utility might analyse your phone use from the notifications (something like Tasker could trigger actions based on notifications appearing or being dismissed).

Because this is a new feature, and 4.3 isn't on many devices yet, it'll be a while before third-party developers invest the time needed to offer these features, but you won't have to wait long.

Comment: Interesting, it would make sense for them to at least have a way to get there especially since its a Settings shortcut...